# Log4j configuration via JVM argument(s)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

What variables do I have to set/pass as arguments to the JVM to get Log4j to run properly? And by properly I mean not complain and print to the console.  Can I see a typical example?

Note: I need to avoid creating a `log4j.properties` file in the application.

Comment: Reader beware: important to notice that the question is asking about log4j, not log4j2.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Do you have a log4j configuration file ? Just reference it using

```
-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}
```

where {path to file} should be prefixed with `file:`

**Edit:** If you are working with log4j2, you need to use

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile={path to file}
```

Taken from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001970/552525

Comment: Brian - not exactly what I was looking for, but I think it is a decent compromise between moving a file into my application and setting the properties via JVM args.

Comment: I think that as your application becomes more complex (if it will) then the file becomes more manageable as you configure it more. However I confess I'm guessing as to your use case here.

Comment: In case of logback.xml, -Dlogback.configuration={path to file} is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: `{path to file}` needs to be prepended with `file:` for this to work.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I've amended appropriately

Comment: Can you tell me how can we specify {path to file} in Linux eclipse

Comment: Watch out if using **Log4j 2** as the property name and syntax changed. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34001970/2245051).

Comment: @BrianAgnew,  what is difference between `-J-Dlog4j.ConfigurationFile` and `-Dlog4j.ConfigurationFile`?

Comment: `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.level=INFO`

Answer (score 169):

The solution is using of the following JVM argument:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}
```

If the file is NOT in the classpath (in `WEB-INF/classes` in case of Tomcat) but somewhere on you disk, use `file:`, like

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:\Users\me\log4j.xml
```

More information and examples here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: For Logback: `-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:\logback-test.xml`

Comment: +1 for mentioning file (reiterating what Tim said.  This has driven me crazy with log4j a number of times.

Comment: Another JVM argument very handy to debug log4j config: `-Dlog4j.debug`

Comment: Is it possible to use relative path with this method?

Answer (score 48):

This configuration seems to have changed in **Log4j 2**:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:C:\Users\me\log4j.xml
```

See: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: This gives me the following exception. C:\Development\Eclipses\EclipseMars\file:C:\Users\ABC\log4j2.xml   How do I make the path absolute

Comment: For Docker Containers, I used `JAVA_PARAMS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2-container.xml"` if the Docker Image supports overriding the JAVA_PARAMS with env vars and the file is inside the Jar.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is already answered, but because you said, this isn't exactly what you are looking for, I would like to point out the following alternative:

You can also use a configuration class instead of the properties or xml file.

```
-Dlog4j.configuratorClass=com.foo.BarConfigurator
```

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html for details.

Comment: This is the correct solution if someone wants to avoid creating a config file.  Inside your own custom Configurator class you could call BasicConfigurator(), or create your own Loggers and Appenders however you want.  But I would much prefer a config file!

Answer (score 14):

Late to the party as since 2015, Log4J 1.x has reached [EOL](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Log4J 2.x onwards the [JVM option](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) should be `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<filename>`

---

*P.S. `<filename>` could be a file relative to the class path **without** the `file:` as suggested in the other answers.*

Comment: Important answer, as the other answers are not longer valid.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, as long as your log4j.properties file is on the classpath, Log4j should just automatically pick it up at JVM startup.

Comment: This is true: the -Dlog4j.configuration is only needed if the file were not in the classpath or if you want to use a file that is not the first one found in the classpath

Answer (score 2):

Relative Path is also ok:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:".\log4j.properties" -jar com.your-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:".\log4j.xml" -jar com.your-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle. You can apply 'aplication' plugin and use the following command

```
  applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
             "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=your.xml",
                              ]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the page ([Log4j2 - Automatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)) Log4j2 needs:

`-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=<path to file>`

> Log4j will inspect the "log4j2.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension. Note that this is not restricted to a location on the local file system and may contain a URL.

Taken from: [Log4j2 - Automatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration)

Answer (score 0):

I used this two commands below with weblogic 12 and it works for log4j2.xml

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=<path to file>
-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=<path to file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following JVM argument:
`-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.level=INFO`

Source:
https://medium.com/@kasunbg/change-log4j2-default-logging-level-to-info-b25db8723eb9