# How to get logs from a JAVA file

Tags: java, shell, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am having a seperate jar file which do some stuffs. Which is actually deployed in tomcat. Inside that jar I have a java file with main method. Say the class name is StartPoint. I am calling that main method from a shell script by "java StartPoint checkStatus". The main method validates the checkStatus param and do the job accordingly. All java files inside the jar uses log4j and uses log.info/log.debug for logging. These logs are working fine if  tomcat is up. Due to some requirement I triggered the main method from a shell script and now I am unable to get those log information. Please help how can I get the logs added using logger.info/debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing additional parameter with log4j config file path:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}
```

[how-do-i-set-log4j-level-on-the-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126709/how-do-i-set-log4j-level-on-the-command-line)

[log4j-configuration-via-jvm-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778933/log4j-configuration-via-jvm-arguments)

Comment: Hi this should be fine if I am acessing my application using tomcat. What I am using is a stand alone java program which is inside my project's jar. I am calling that particular file alone from shell script.

Comment: So how are you invoking this app form shell script? Something like this: java -jar <file_name>.jar?

Comment: export CLASSPATH=...all my jars including project.jar-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}   java -cp ${CLASSPATH} com.pack.StartPoint checkStatus

Comment: You have environment property in CLASSPATH: '-Dlog4j.configuration={path to file}'. I think it shuld be like this  java -Dlog4j.configuration={path to file} -cp ${CLASSPATH} com.pack.StartPoint checkStatus

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you just need to make sure that `log4j.properties/log4j.xml` is on the classpath when you call the StartPoint main method directly.

Comment: I have WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar in my classpath is this enough?

Comment: no just jar is not enough, basically log4j reads configuration such as where to put logs(console,file etc), file rolling, logs date format etc from log4j.properties/log4j.xml. You need to make sure that this config file is present in your classpath.