# log4j config file not getting loaded

Tags: shell, log4j

I am running a shell script to execute a java program. when invoking the java program i am passing

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=${SRD_BATCH_HOME}/propertyfile/log4j.properties
```

When i run the program i see this on top of the log

> ```
> log4j: Trying to find [/some path/log4j.properties] using context classloader
> ```
>
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4aad3ba4. 
>   log4j: Trying to find [/some path/log4j.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4aad3ba4 class loader.
>   log4j: Trying to find [/some path/log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
>   log4j: Could not find resource: [/some path/log4j.properties].

But my log4j is lying right at this place //log4j.properties

I added `BasicConfigurator.configure()` in my java program and the logs started printing but now its printing everything as its not looking at my properties file. can someone help out on what could be wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/12579674/603516

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "file:/" to the start of the file path

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/${SRD_BATCH_HOME}/propertyfile/log4j.properties
```

as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875663/log4j-properties-in-a-custom-place/875705#comment17216594_875705)

Comment: That didnt work. But adding the whole of properties folder in classpath solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure there is only one / after file: