# How to set a folder for logs during runtime using log4j in java?

Tags: java, log4j

I am writing a simple sockets-chat on Java. For logging i use log4j. The back-end includes `Server.class` (handles general logic) and `ClientListener.class` (takes and operates with user's requests), both of them are threads.

### The problem is:

I need to save logs into different directories depending on whether an event to be logged has occured in the `Server` or in a `ClientListener` of user **X**.

### How I see a solution:

- `Server` always logs into *serv_base_dir/logs/logs.txt*
- `ClientListeners` logs into folers with users data e.g.
  *serv_base_dir/users/**X**/logs/logs.txt*

### The question is:

How to set a logs folder where they are to be saved in during server is running?

### **PS**

I have read [Log4j config - different logs to different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322602/log4j-config-different-logs-to-different-files)
 article, but it does not completely solve my problem because I need to set the folder during the runtime, not before compillation
I would be greatful to any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a directory named specific user unknown until runtime,
you can solve it by passing argument to log4j property file during runtime.

[Pass argument to log4j file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442087/pass-argument-to-log4j-file)

[Sample code]

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyClass
{
    public static Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("test", "hello");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("./log4j.properties");

        mLogger.debug("Hello world!");

        // modify variable and re-configure
        System.setProperty("test", "bye");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("./log4j.properties");

        mLogger.debug("byebye");
    }
}
```

[log4j.properties]

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./${test}.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: no, this can change the value continuously. I added example code.