# How to print logs on console in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, console, log4j

Can't get logs to show up on console while running unit tests. Instead, I see this message every time I run a unit test -

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger. 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

log4j.properties contains this -

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

I'm pretty sure that this needs to be configured in run configurations but just can't get it to work. Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your log4j.properties located?

Comment: It's inside the project folder. Have marked that as a resource folder.

Comment: Is *.properties included in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Resource patterns?

Comment: Did you define the `stdout` appender in `log4j.properties` too?

Comment: @yole - Thanks for pointing that out, it wasn't. Have added it now. But it's not working.

Comment: @maba - have this in the properties file log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work! Added this to VM options -

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:{path-to-properties-file}/log4j.properties
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778933/log4j-configuration-via-jvm-arguments) by 30thh.

I had it added in my default unit test configuration, but it wasn't being picked up by current configuration.