# error setting up log4j configuration file

Tags: java, log4j

I must be doing something stupid here:

```
C:\tmp\log>java -jar logorrhea.jar -Dlog4j.configurationFile=c:/tmp/log/mblog4j.properties

ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I'm following the directions in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html to set the `log4j.configurationFile` system property but it doesn't seem to work. (and there is a file called `c:/tmp/log/mblog4j.properties` present)

What could be going wrong?

My mblog4j.properties file looks like this:

```
# Setup loggers: default threshold = ERROR, but special stuff = INFO
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,FILE
log4j.logger.com.example.mypackage=INFO,FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=c:/tmp/log/mb4j.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778933/log4j-configuration-via-jvm-arguments - you need the file: prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` needs to go *before* the `-jar logorrhea.jar` (and the `file:` prefix needs to be there as stdunbar says)

correct syntax:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:c:/tmp/log/mblog4j.properties -jar logorrhea.jar
```

---

Also, the log4j 2 configuration is totally different than log4j 1.x; I had to revise my log configuration file to:

```
# Setup loggers: default threshold = ERROR, but special stuff = ALL
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = c:/tmp/log/mb4j.log

appenders = FILE

appender.FILE.type=File
appender.FILE.name=File
appender.FILE.append=false
appender.FILE.immediateFlush=true
appender.FILE.fileName=${filename}
appender.FILE.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.FILE.layout.pattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

loggers = mb

logger.mb.name = com.example.mypackage
logger.mb.level = all
logger.mb.appenderRefs = FILE
logger.mb.appenderRef.FILE.ref = File
```