# Log4J configuration file ignored by IntelliJ

Tags: logging, log4j, configuration-files

I am trying to add a custom `Log4J` configuration to a large software project built using `IntelliJ 2016.1`, but the IDE seems to completely ignore the properties file supplied (`log4j.properties` in plain text - not XML) in unit tests.

More specifically, running tests written against `JUnit` 4, `IntelliJ` does not show any logging messages without going to the `Run | Edit configurations` menu and then supplying the following argument to the VM, via the `VM Options` box:

- -Dlog4j.configuration=/absolute/path/to/log4j.properties

The weird thing is that the contents of the file specified are completely ignored.

So, even if the above path is replaced by a path to a file that does not even exist, or if the path is deleted altogether, `IntelliJ` continues printing logging messages in the same layout as before, as if it reads the properties from a completely different location. Removing the `-Dlog4j.configuration` parameter, stops logging messages entirely. It's as if the IDE understands the `-Dlog4j.configuration` as an ON/OFF switch for logging, without caring about any path supplied with it.

There are multiple `Log4J` and `SLF4J` JARs in the project classpath and numerous `log4j.properties` files around, but even deleting all of the latter doesn't change the logging output. Apparently the properties file specified via `-Dlog4j.configuration` is ignored by `Log4J` all the time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually simple. Essentially, the file has to be specified as a `URL`, i.e. one has to supply the configuration as follows:

- -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///absolute/path/to/log4j.properties

Apparently, the prefix `file:` works too, without the full `URI` scheme syntax `file:///`.

This is also described in the answers of a [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778933/log4j-configuration-via-jvm-arguments).