# Show Log4J2 Output in Eclipse Console

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, log4j2

I've been unable to configure my Web app project to show LOG4J2 output in the **Eclipse Console**. It goes to some tomcat log location.

Tried all the threads and nothing helped.

First, suppose the LOG4J2.XML is originally here: `./appconfig/dev/log4j2.xml`

[image]

I followed an example and added this folder as a Library under Class Path, but that didn't work.

[image]

Then I tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47068673/1005607) with a -D param for the config file,

[image]

Also tried adding it to the location which DeploymentAssembly will move to WEB-INF/classes,

[image]

Nothing helped, I'm not getting my Eclipse Console output for this app for `log.info` / `log.error`, except for Hibernate-only output.

LOG4J2.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DATE} [%X{sessionId}] %X{userId} %-5p %c{1}(Line %L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="/local/content/tomcat/idp/logs/idp.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="/local/content/tomcat/idp/logs/idp.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{DATE} [%X{sessionId}] %X{userId} %-5p %c{1}(Line %L) - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="gov" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.orm" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.hibernate.sql" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.web" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="net.sf.ehcache" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Please share your log4j2.xml file.

Comment: added to OP ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out. We had to remove `additivity="false"` from the Log4J2.xml.

Thus, the file is **without additivity=false**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DATE} [%X{sessionId}] %X{userId} %-5p %c{1}(Line %L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="/local/content/tomcat/idp/logs/idp.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="/local/content/tomcat/idp/logs/idp.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{DATE} [%X{sessionId}] %X{userId} %-5p %c{1}(Line %L) - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="gov" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.orm" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.hibernate.sql" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.web" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="net.sf.ehcache" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```